# How to disable client-side GRPC server cert hostname validation?

Tags: c++, ssl, grpc

Currently I'm setting up the channel authentication for my gRPC client as follows:

```
std::shared_ptr<grpc::ChannelCredentials> channel_creds;
auto metadata = grpc::ChannelArguments();

// ...
grpc::SslCredentialsOptions sslOpts{};
sslOpts.pem_root_certs = // PEM with the Root CA cert's public key
sslOpts.pem_cert_chain = // PEM for client cert's public key
sslOpts.pem_private_key = // PEM for client cert's private key

channel_creds = grpc::SslCredentials(sslOpts);
metadata.SetSslTargetNameOverride(mbServerCertSubjectName.second.get());

// ...
grpc::CreateCustomChannel(addr_str, channel_creds, metadata);
```

This is almost perfect, but I'd like to disable the certificate name validation: I'd just like to accept anything as long as it chains to the `pem_root_certs` that I provide.

This seems achievable if I could create a [TlsChannelCredentialsOptions](http://TlsChannelCredentialsOptions) struct with its [grpc_tls_server_verification_option](https://grpc.github.io/grpc/cpp/grpc__security__constants_8h.html#aa4b37b544134e070541912584793446a) field set to GRPC_TLS_SKIP_HOSTNAME_VERIFICATION, but the interface for [TlsCredentialsOptions](https://grpc.github.io/grpc/cpp/classgrpc_1_1experimental_1_1_tls_credentials_options.html) is totally different from SslCredentialsOptions and I don't know how to set it up to authenticate based on the PEM files that I'm providing to sslOpts here.

How can I translate my desired logic over to TlsChannelCredentialsOptions?

Answer (score 2):

try this one:

```
grpc::ChannelArguments gargs;
gargs.SetSslTargetNameOverride("domian name you want to ignore");

client client(grpc::CreateCustomChannel("ipverson:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:port", ssl_creds, gargs));
```