# How to encrypt gRPC connections without certificates?

Tags: encryption, grpc

I'm going to be using gRPC for a device to device connection over a network (my device will be running Linux and collecting patient data from various monitors, gRPC will be used by a Windows client system to grab and display that data).

I obviously want to encrypt the data on the wire, but dealing with certificates is going to be a problem for various reasons. I can easily have the server not ask for the client cert, but so far I've been unable to find a way around the client validating the server's cert.

I've got several reasons I don't want to bother with a server cert:

1. The data collection device (the gRPC server) is going to be assigned an IP and name via DHCP in most cases. Which means that when that name changes (at install time, or when they move the device to a different part of the hospital), I have to automatically fixup the certs. Other than shipping a self-signed CA cert and key with the device, I don't know how to do that.
2. There are situations where we're going to want to point client to server via IP, not name. Given that gRPC can't do a cert for an IP (https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/2691), this becomes a configuration that we can't support without doing something to give a name to a thing we only have an IP for (hosts file on the Windows client?). Given the realities of operating in a hospital IT environment, NOT supporting use of IPs instead of names is NOT an option.

Is there some simple way to accommodate this situation? I'm far from an expert on any of this, so it's entirely possible I've missed something very basic.

Is there some simple way to set the name that the client uses to check the server to be different than the name it uses to connect to the server? That way I could just set a fixed name, use that all the time and be fine.

Is there some way to get a gRPC client to not check the server certificate? (I already have the server setup to ignore the client cert).

Is there some other way to get gRPC to encrypt the connection?

I could conceivably set things up to have the client open an ssh tunnel to the server and then run an insecure gRPC connection across that tunnel, but obviously adding another layer to opening the connection is a pain in the neck, and I'm not at all sure how comfortable the client team is going to be with that.

Comment: What programming language(s) will the clients be in?

Comment: I'm not actually sure. The server team is adding this functionality to an existing C++ product, but I don't know if the client team are going to use C++ or C# or something else altogether.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for raising this question! Please see my inline replies below:

> I obviously want to encrypt the data on the wire, but dealing with
> certificates is going to be a problem for various reasons. I can
> easily have the server not ask for the client cert, but so far I've
> been unable to find a way around the client validating the server's
> cert.

There are actually two types of checks happening on the client side: certificate check and the hostname verification check. The former checks the server certificate, to make sure it is trusted by the client; the latter checks the target name with server's identity on the peer certificate. It seems you are suffering with the latter - just want to make sure because you will need to get both of these checks right on the client side, in order to establish a good connection.

> The data collection device (the gRPC server) is going to be assigned
> an IP and name via DHCP in most cases. Which means that when that name
> changes (at install time, or when they move the device to a different
> part of the hospital), I have to automatically fixup the certs. Other
> than shipping a self-signed CA cert and key with the device, I don't
> know how to do that.
>
> There are situations where we're going to want to point client to
> server via IP, not name. Given that gRPC can't do a cert for an IP
> (https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/2691), this becomes a
> configuration that we can't support without doing something to give a
> name to a thing we only have an IP for (hosts file on the Windows
> client?). Given the realities of operating in a hospital IT
> environment, NOT supporting use of IPs instead of names is NOT an
> option.

gRPC supports IP address(it is also mentioned in the last comment of the issue you brought up). You will have to put your IP address in the SAN field of server's certificate, instead of the CN field. It's true that it will be a problem if your IP will change dynamically - that's why we need DNS domain name, and set up the PKI infrastructure. If that's a bit heavy amount of work for your team, see below :)

> Is there some simple way to accommodate this situation? I'm far from
> an expert on any of this, so it's entirely possible I've missed
> something very basic.
>
> Is there some simple way to set the name that the client uses to check
> the server to be different than the name it uses to connect to the
> server? That way I could just set a fixed name, use that all the time
> and be fine.

You can directly use IP address to connect, and override the target name in the channel args. Note that the overridden name should match the certificate sent from the server. Depending on which credential type you use, it could be slightly different. I suggest you read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68305089/how-to-disable-client-side-grpc-server-cert-hostname-validation) question.

> Is there some way to get a gRPC client to not check the server
> certificate? (I already have the server setup to ignore the client
> cert).
>
> Is there some other way to get gRPC to encrypt the connection?

Note that: Even if you don't use any certificate on the wire, if you are sure  the correct credential type(either SSL or TLS) is used, then the data on the wire is encrypted. Certificate helps you to make sure the endpoint to which you are connecting is verified.  Failing to use certificates will leave your application to Man-In-The-Middle attacks. Hope this can help you better understand the goals and make the right judgement for your team.

Comment: So yes, I missed something basic - in the C++ version, grpc::ChannelArguments::SetSslTargetNameOverride lets me then use grpc::CreateCustomChannel in the client with a fixed server name. At that point I can simply issue the servers with fixed-name certs and let gRPC proceed normally, getting the encryption on the wire that I need.

Comment: And yes, this does open us up to MITM attacks, but it's on a local network, and an MITM attack should be a bit harder than sniffing the wire for data, so I think it will be sufficiently secure for our purposes, while allowing the customers to get things working easily.